# Add end of line comment to vim syntax

Tags: syntax, comments, vim

Not every command in Vim allows you to add end-of-line comments. Sometimes the `"` is valid as an argument, so it would be ambiguous. **However,** if you insert a pipe, the command is ended and you *can* insert a comment. So you can actually achieve reliable end of line comments in vim thusly:

```
noremap ' ` |" Use single quote as alternate range key
```

Neat, right? But the `syntax/vim.vim` file doesn't recognize this as an end of line comment. How do I tell Vim to recognize this syntax?

I found this in `syntax/vim.vim`:

```
syn match   vimLineComment  +^[ \t:]*".*$+  contains=@vimCommentGroup,vimCommentString,vimCommentTitle
```

I tried adding something like this to my `~/.vimrc`, but there is no effect. VimScript is hard. :/

```
syntax match vimLineComment '|".*$+'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you cannot use in-line comments for `map`s

```
:h map-comments
```

you will see:

```
                            *map-comments*
It is not possible to put a comment after these commands, because the '"'
character is considered to be part of the {lhs} or {rhs}.
```

I hope this answers your question.

### hack

Okay， you may have good reason to do that.

Only define `syn match vimLineComment` is not enough, you have to overwrite the `vimMapRhs` syntax.  so these two lines will make `|"foo bar` highlighted as comment:

```
syn match vimMapRhs '.*\ze|\s*".*'
syn match vimLineComment '|\s*".*$'
```

[image]
this may change the "comment" highlight, but I don't recommend to do it.

Comment: You absolutely can. See the pipe? The comment is a separate "command" in this case. Try it. I added some introductory text to make the context clearer.

Comment: @sidewaysmilk I see what you mean. personally it is not "neat" at all. why you need do this hack? btw, you have to exclude `\|"foo` case, since it could be a literal pipe in `rhs`

Comment: **Why** isn't really the point. My question is how I add an end-of-line comment token to Vim's VimScript syntax. This information would be useful for anybody trying to add/fix a comment token in any syntax. If you're just curious, it's because I have a long list of commands in my ~/.vimrc that I'd like to comment in this way. It's just a preference.

Comment: The `syn match`... lines only worked for me once I put them into `~/nvim/after/syntax/vim.vim` using Neovim.

Comment: completely off-topic, but your theme looks really great. How did you set it? I'm guessing it's taken from colors of the terminal and whatnot, so what terminal program do you use? I'd love to set it up too

Comment: @Daniel I've created a repo for my theme. Details of my theme: https://github.com/sk1418/last256 BTW, the terminal I am using is urxvt. But the vim in this answer is GVIM

Answer (score 4):

### Background

- vim 7.3 all platforms
- vimscript language (used in vim files)

### Problem

The vimscript language supports comments, but end of line comments do not always work predictably, because end of line comments can be mistakenly interpreted by vim as part of the command.

Adding end of line comments is problemmatic in vimscript, because it does not work with all commands.

### Solutions

- 1) use the pipe character `:help :bar` to create a separate Ex command

  - this is the solution enumerated by @sidewaysmilk
- 2) simply add the comment below the relevant vimscript command on the next line
- 3) use the execute command (see `:help :execute` )

### Pitfalls

- Solution 1) is a somewhat unconventional use of the pipe (aka `:bar`)
- Not all commands support the pipe character (see e.g. `:help :execute`)
- Solution 2) may not be desirable for the readability of the vimscript, and it does not directly solve the issue in the OP
- searching for this feature on the internet is tricky because it turns up links related to comments in general-purpose programming contexts, unrelated to vimscript

### See also

Vim help links (enter these directly into vim Cmdline-mode):

- `:help vim-script-intro | /comments for some commands`
- `:help :bar`
- `:help Command-line-mode`

Web links:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimscript
- https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vim+vim-script-intro+comments

Answer (score -1):

+1 fot "This is not "neat" at all":

```
noremap ' ` |" Use single quote as alternate range key
```

My preference is **to use end of line comment (without adding `|`) where vimL allows**.
The pain point is:
It's hard to remember when vimL allows that. (so some people never uses end of line comment in vimL, which may narrow his choice of formating)

Inspired by the OP, we can utilize the syntax highlight. (But I don't know how to implement yet)

Below is some information which seems to be needed:

Relevant lines in the  syntax.vim:
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/neovim/0.6.1/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim

```
syn region  vimString   start="^\s*\\\z(['"]\)" skip='\\\\\|\\\z1' end="\z1" oneline keepend contains=@vimStringGroup,vimContinue

    syn match vimComment  excludenl +\s"[^\-:.%#=*].*$+lc=1   contains=@vimCommentGroup,vimCommentString
    syn match vimComment  +\<endif\s\+".*$+lc=5   contains=@vimCommentGroup,vimCommentString
    syn match vimComment  +\<else\s\+".*$+lc=4    contains=@vimCommentGroup,vimCommentString


    syn region  vimCommentString    contained oneline start='\S\s\+"'ms=e   end='"'
    hi def link vimCommentString vimString


    " end of line comment
        syn match   vimLineComment  +^[ \t:]*".*$+  contains=@vimCommentGroup,vimCommentString,vimCommentTitle
        hi def link vimLineComment   vimComment

        syn match   vim9LineComment +^[ \t:]\+#.*$+ contains=@vimCommentGroup,vimCommentString,vimCommentTitle
        hi def link vim9Comment  Comment


    syn match   vimCommentTitle '"\s*\%([sS]:\|\h\w*#\)\=\u\w*\(\s\+\u\w*\)*:'hs=s+1    contained contains=vimCommentTitleLeader,vimTodo,@vimCommentGroup
    hi def link vimCommentTitle  PreProc
    syn match   vimCommentTitleLeader   '"\s\+'ms=s+1   contained

    syn match   vimContinue "^\s*\\"
```

[image]